# I've deleted cryptsetup-initramfs

Tags: encryption, lvm, delete, luks, cryptsetup

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (5.15.-10088.98) with **LUKS LVM** and have done something stupid.

I've tried `sudo apt upgrade` and get the following problem:

```
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/system-swap)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-10088-tuxedo with 1.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes initramfs-tools (--configure):
 »installiertes initramfs-tools-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterproze
ss gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Than I've done this:
`sudo apt remove initramfs-tools`
`sudo apt clean`
`sudo apt install initramfs-tools`

After that I have seen that **cryptsetup was deleted**:

```
    brltty cryptsetup-initramfs dmraid initramfs-tools kpartx-boot
```

When I try:

`apt show cryptsetup -a`

it shows

```
Package: cryptsetup
Version: 2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Cryptsetup Team <pkg-cryptsetup-devel@alioth-lists.debian.net>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 407 kB
Depends: cryptsetup-bin (>= 2:1.6.0), dmsetup, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.15)
Recommends: cryptsetup-initramfs, cryptsetup-run
Suggests: dosfstools, keyutils, liblocale-gettext-perl
Breaks: cryptsetup-run (<< 2:2.1.0-6)
Replaces: cryptsetup-run (<< 2:2.1.0-6)
Homepage: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup
Task: server, cloud-image, ubuntu-live, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, xubuntu-live, lubuntu-live, ubuntustudio-dvd-live, ubuntukylin-live, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-live
Download-Size: 159 kB
APT-Sources: https://mirrors.tuxedocomputers.com/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
Description: Unterstützung für Festplattenverschlüsselung - Startskripte
 Cryptsetup bietet eine Kommandozeilenschnittstelle zur Konfiguration
 verschlüsselter Geräte (wie beispielsweise /home- oder Swap-Partitionen).
 Das wird durch die Nutzung des Ziels »dm-crypt« des Device-Mappers des
 Linux-Kernels getan. Es bietet Unterstützung für LUKS (Linux Unified Key
 Setup).
 .
 Cryptsetup ist rückwärtskompatibel mit dem on-disk-Format von cryptoloop,
 unterstützt aber auch sicherere Formate. Dieses Paket bietet außerdem
 Unterstützung für die automatische Konfiguration verschlüsselter Geräte
 während des Bootvorgangs (mittels der Konfigurationsdatei /etc/crypttab).
 Weitere Merkmale sind die Unterstützung von cryptoroot durch die
 initramfs- Werkzeuge und verschiedene Methoden, eine Passphrase oder einen
 Schlüssel zu lesen.
 .
 Dieses Paket stellt die Wrapper cryptdisk_start und cryptdisk_stop sowie
 luksformat bereit.
```

Out of fear that my laptop will not be decrypted when booting, I have not turned it off yet.
I don't know if I'm overreacting or if my fear is justified.

**Is there a way to fix the problem that may exist?**